# A special improper integral

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, hypergeometric-function

I need to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^\infty  dx \left(\frac{x^2}{2x^2+1}\right)^a\left(\frac{x^2}{2x^2+t_y^2}\right)^b\left(\frac{x^2}{2x^2+t_z^2}\right)^c\frac{1}{x^3}$$

where, $a$, $b$, $c$, $t_y$ and $t_z$ are real.

I have succeeded to perform this integral only for two special cases:
1. $t_y$ = $t_z$ =1 and 2. $t_z$ = $t_y$

I shall be very thankful if someone could suggest a way to perform the integral above for $t_z \neq t_y$. Looking forward to hearing.

Comment: Can any additional assumptions be made about the parameters besides being real-valued? For example, might we assume $1<a+b+c$? (I'm fairly sure the integral diverges otherwise...)

Comment: David, not really. Consider the case 1: $t_y$ = $t_z$ =1, the integral becomes:$$\frac{2^{-a-b-c}}{a+b+c-1}$$, if $a$+$b$+$c$ > 1.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you sure we can't assume $1<a+b+c$? The integral won't have a finite value if $a+b+c\le1$.

Comment: What makes you think so?

Comment: Just look at the case $a=b=c=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^\infty\left(\dfrac{x^2}{2x^2+1}\right)^a\left(\dfrac{x^2}{2x^2+t_y^2}\right)^b\left(\dfrac{x^2}{2x^2+t_z^2}\right)^c\dfrac{1}{x^3}~dx$$

$$=-2^{-a-b-c}\int_0^\infty\left(\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{2x^2}}\right)^a\left(\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{t_y^2}{2x^2}}\right)^b\left(\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{t_z^2}{2x^2}}\right)^c~d\left(\dfrac{1}{2x^2}\right)$$

$$=2^{-a-b-c}\int_0^\infty\left(1+x\right)^{-a}\left(1+t_y^2x\right)^{-b}\left(1+t_z^2x\right)^{-c}~dx$$

$$=2^{-a-b-c}\int_0^1\left(1+\dfrac{u}{1-u}\right)^{-a}\left(1+\dfrac{t_y^2u}{1-u}\right)^{-b}\left(1+\dfrac{t_z^2u}{1-u}\right)^{-c}~d\left(\dfrac{u}{1-u}\right)$$

$$=2^{-a-b-c}\int_0^1(1-u)^{a+b+c-2}(1+(t_y^2-1)u)^{-b}(1+(t_z^2-1)u)^{-c}~du$$

$$=\dfrac{2^{-a-b-c}F_1(1,b,c,a+b+c;1-t_y^2,1-t_z^2)}{a+b+c-1}~\text{when}~0<t_y,t_z<\sqrt2$$

(according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series#Integral_representations)

$$=2^{-a-b-c}\int_0^1u^{a+b+c-2}((t_y^2-1)+(2-t_y^2)u)^{-b}((t_z^2-1)+(2-t_z^2)u)^{-c}~du$$

$$=\dfrac{2^{-a-b-c}}{(t_y^2-1)^b(t_z^2-1)^c}\int_0^1u^{a+b+c-2}\left(1-\dfrac{(t_y^2-2)u}{t_y^2-1}\right)^{-b}\left(1-\dfrac{(t_z^2-2)u}{t_z^2-1}\right)^{-c}~du$$

$$=\dfrac{2^{-a-b-c}}{(a+b+c-1)(t_y^2-1)^b(t_z^2-1)^c}F_1\left(a+b+c-1,b,c,a+b+c;\dfrac{t_y^2-2}{t_y^2-1},\dfrac{t_z^2-2}{t_z^2-1}\right)~\text{when}~t_y,t_z\geq\sqrt2$$

(according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appell_series#Integral_representations)

Comment: Thanks Harry Peter. But your approach doesn't solve the actual integral as Mathematica is trying to evaluate it involving AppellF1 function on $t_y$, $t_z$ and $x$ whose value is not defined at $x \to \infty$. Could you please throw some more light to this issue that might eventually solve this improper integral? Thanks

Comment: Harry Peter's approach leads the integral to be,

$$=2^{-a-b-c}\frac{1}{a-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)^{-1+a}\left(\frac{1}{1-{t_y}^2}\right)^{b}\left(\frac{1}{1-{t_z}^2}\right)^{c}AppellF1[1-a,b,c,2-a,\frac{(1+x)\space{t_y}^2}{{t_y}^2-1},\frac{(1+x)\space{t_z}^2}{{t_z}^2-1}]\vert_{0}^{\infty}$$, which is indeterminate due to the presence of $(x+1)$ in the last two terms in $AppellF1$, at $x\to\infty$, although then the terms left to $AppellF1 =0$, giving overall "$0 \space\times\space indeterminate$" - could it be then said $0$?